# How to Find String with comm separated value in table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Id  vDivisionNo
1    1,9
2    9
3    1
4    9,1
```

i have using char index but not find value

```
select * from DivisionMst where CHARINDEX(',' + vLocationNo + ',', ','+ '9,14' + ',') > 0
```

And Try this

```
select * from DivisionMst where CHARINDEX(',' + '9,14' + ',', ','+ vLocationNo + ',') > 0
```

But Not working please help me.

Comment: Normalize your table structure. **Never store data in this way**.

Answer (score 0):

use this below query to find the answer

```
SELECT        *
FROM          DivisionMst
WHERE        (vDivisionNo LIKE '%,%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should, if possible, normalize your database.
Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutly yes!**.

If, however, you can't change the database structure, you can use LIKE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DivisionMst 
WHERE ',' + vLocationNo + ',' LIKE '%,'+ '9,14' + ',%'
```

btw, your sample data does not contain a column name `vLocationNo`, nor does it contain a value `'9,14'`.